# Compiler warning when lazy loading component with dynamic import

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular9

i am using Angular 9 and its ivy compiler.

I try to lazy load a component with the dynamic import function and the componentFactoryResolver:

```
const comp = await import('path/component.ts').then(x => x.component)
const factory = this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory(comp);
this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory)
```

It works as expected, i can load the component and use it, but when the lazy loaded component uses a sibling component declared in the same module as the lazy loaded componente i get the following warning:

*WARNING in ./src/app/core/components/component.html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.*

The problem with this warning is, that it apparently creates .js files in the dist folder containing the warning.

Answer (score 1):

When you lazy load a component with componentFactoryResolver, that component isn't connected to the module you are declaring it, so it doesn't know what is that other component.

I suggest reading more about it here:

- https://indepth.dev/lazy-loading-angular-modules-with-ivy/

Comment: Funny thing is that when i create a module in the same file which declares both components, i can use the component and it gets rendered without any error message. Except the warning in the console. I will try to lazy load the whole module and test it, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

I am using dynamic paths in the import() function to reduce the path length you need to write when adding a new component.

Apparently webpack can not handle such dynamic paths and prints out warnings.

I now created a dictionary of all components with the whole import like this:

```
componentPath: () => import('./src/core/component/component.ts')
```

Edit:

```
tsconfig.json:
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["environments/*"]
    },
}
```

An example in my environment.ts:

```
        export const DynamicComponents = {
    
       exampleComp = () => import('./src/core/exampleComp/example-comp.component').(x => x.ExampleComp)
       ...
       
    }
```

The component file:

```
@Component(...)
export class ExampleComp {
}


@NgModule({
declarations: [ExampleComp]
}...)

export class ExampleCompModule {
}
```

Comment: please, can you provide more code of your solution (tsconfig.json, angular.json, lazy loaded component and module source)?
I have exactly the same issue, but I am already using full paths in imports...

Comment: @EduardVoid i edited my answer. If it doesn't help you, can you open a new issue with more details?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had a wrong path in import, but it takes time to realize... :) It's working now.